# Angular 2 Promise issue

Tags: typescript, angular, es6-promise

I am starting to learn Angular 2 and I am having issues with using Promise.then to return my object from a service. I am currently only using a fixed array (COACHES) for faking a database call. The function in my service is as follows

```
getCoach(id: number) {
    return Promise.resolve(COACHES).then(
        coaches => coaches.filter(coach => coach.id == id)[0]
    );
}
```

I then use this in my coach_detail.component.ts in an ngOnInit hook to get the coach object I want using Route Params:

```
export class CoachDetailComponent implements OnInit {

    coach: Coach;

    constructor(
        private _coachService: CoachService,
        private _routeParams: RouteParams) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        let id = +this._routeParams.get('id');
        this._coachService.getCoach(id).then(coach => this.coach = coach);
        console.log(this.coach);
    }
}
```

I can see in my console that the promise is returning back to my component but `console.log(this.coach)` is returning as `undefined`

Any help is much appreciated as I use a similar logic in a different component to return the entire list of coaches and this works fine!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `console.log()` is called before promise chain is exacuted.

```
ngOnInit() {
    let id = +this._routeParams.get('id');
    this._coachService.getCoach(id).then(coach => { 
      this.coach = coach 
      console.log(this.coach); // not undefined
    });
    console.log(this.coach); // undefined
}
```

Comment: But am I not calling the console.log on the "coach" variable i defined in component? The `this._coachService.getCoach(id)` should be assigning the returned object to `this.coach`. My issue really is that my arrow function is not assigning properly

Comment: Hm, your code looks fine. Can you create a plunker with example?

Comment: Bit unwieldy but here you go:https://plnkr.co/edit/Sk4GH2mgoJ2XkQ7Tr1qN The issue I am talking about is when you go onto the "Coaches" page and then try to select a coach name.

Comment: The issue happens because you are using `coach` before it's assigned. When component is created and before `ngOnInit()` is called template tries to access this variable. You can use [Elvis Operator](https://angular.io/cheatsheet) in your template `<h1>{{coach?.first_name}} {{coach?.surname}}</h1>` https://plnkr.co/edit/p4YEbGUVs2jPQ2gJpi9n

Comment: I see thank you so much. Is there something else I could have done which means I wouldn't have to use the Elvis operator? Or is this standard practice? I notice that the ang2 tutorial uses ngIf instead

Comment: You can try to avoid displaying data directly (ng1 way) and use a "proxy" - some kind of `app state`. This way your view layer (templates) would only display what's in the `app state`, and your services would provide data for the `app state`.

Comment: Take a look at [`@ngrx/store`](https://github.com/ngrx/store) it's an implementation of "redux pattern" for ng2. Can be a bit overwhelming at first, but worth every hour (or week :) spent trying to figure it out (;

Comment: OK thank you. One last question then ill leave you alone! Why do we need to use ? in this example but we dont need to do it for the entire coaches list where I am using `*ngFor="coach of coaches"` does the ngFor mean it isnt trying to access until after the ngOninit?

Comment: It's just how [ngFor](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-beta.7/modules/angular2/src/common/directives/ng_for.ts#L63-L78) works - it has some internal checks `if (isBlank(this._differ) && isPresent(value))`...